Positive scalar curvature Einstein manifolds are noncollapsed
I am currently working through some of the exercises in Ricci Solitons in Low Dimensions by Bennett Chow, and I've been stuck on Exercise 1.23. It asks you to prove that positive scalar curvature Einstein solutions to the Ricci flow are $\kappa$-noncollapsed for some $\kappa>0$.
In particular, it asks to show that if $(M^n,g)$ is an Einstein manifold with $Ric=\frac{\lambda}{2}g$ for some $\lambda>0$, then the Ricci flow solution $(M,g(t):=(1-\lambda t)g)$ is $\kappa$-noncollapsed at all scales for some $\kappa>0$. Of course, since noncollapsing is a scale-invariant condition and Einstein solutions evolve only by scaling the initial metric $g$, it suffices to prove that $(M,g)$ is noncollapsed at all scales. To this end, given $r>0$ and $p\in M$, we would like to show that
$$ \frac{n\lambda}{2}=R\leq r^{-2} $$
on $B_r(p)$ implies that $Vol B_r(p)\geq\kappa r^n$, where $R$ denotes the scalar curvatre. (This text opts to use scalar curvature to define noncollapsing rather than the norm $|Rm|$ of the full Riemann curvature tensor.) The bound on the curvature clearly forces $r\leq\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\lambda}}$, but I can't seem to relate this to the volume of the geodesic ball $B_r(p)$ to obtain the desired lower bound. I'd like to be able to set $\kappa=(\frac{n\lambda}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}$ based on the inequality above, but I am having a difficult time finding the connection to the volume. Any help would be much appreciated.

I believe the Bishop-Gromov inequality would apply here. Have you tried that?

I had tried using Bishop-Gromov, but it only seems to yield upper bounds on the volume $VolB_r(p)$ of the form $VolB_r(p)\leq Vol_{S^n(k)}B_r$, where $k=\sqrt{\frac{2(n-1)}{\lambda}}$.

Let $g$ be a metric on a closed manifold $M$. Let $V_g(M)$ be the volume of $M$ and $d_g(M)$ be the diameter of $M$. Given $p \in M$ and $R> 0$, let $V_g(B(p,R))$ denote the volume of the geodesic ball of radius $R$ centered at $p$. Let $V_0(R)$ denote the volume of a Euclidean ball with radius $R$.
If the Ricci curvature of $g$ is nonnegative, the Bishop-Gromov inequality states that for any $0 \le r \le R$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{V_g(B(p,r))}{V_g(B(p,R))} &\ge \frac{V_0(r)}{V_0(R)}.
\end{align*}
If we set $R = d_g(M)$, then we get
$$ V_g(B(p,r)) \ge \kappa r^n, $$
where
$$ \kappa = \frac{V_g(M)}{(d_g(M))^n}. $$

Thank you, I see now that I was overcomplicating things. I have one remaining question regarding your choice of $R=\frac{1}{2}d_g(M)$. I don't see that $V_g(B(p,R))=V_g(M)$ for this choice of $R$. For instance, on the unit $n$-sphere with (intrinsic) diameter $\pi$, the ball $B(p,\frac{1}{2}\pi)$ is only a hemisphere. To get a geodesic ball covering the entire manifold $M$, wouldn't one have to take $R=d_g(M)$ on the nose? This doesn't seem to change much about the overall argument other than the precise value of $\kappa$ of course.

Yes, you are right. I didn't think this through carefully enough. Many thanks for the correction. I'll edit my answer and happily get rid of the annoying power of $2$.
